# Chained promises give undefined function error, but I can execute the functions separately

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to chain some API calls before setting the `textContent` of some `spans` in my webpage. I can execute the following ajax API calls separately by pasting them into the console, but when I chain them as promises I get `getFirstData() is undefined`.

```
var first_data = [],
    second_data = [];

function getFirstData(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/API/first-data?format=json"
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            first_data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            return Promise.resolve('1');
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
}

/*getSecondData is the same, but with a different API url. I'll DRY these 
two into one function that takes a url argument when I get it working.*/

getFirstData().then(getSecondData).then(createPage);
```

This is between `<script>` tags just before `</body>`. So what's wrong with the call to `getFirstData()` on the last line that causes the interpreter to say it's `undefined`? For reference, in the network log, getSecondData() is sent and returns just fine.

(Note: I'm specifically trying to do this without JQuery).

Comment: Can you make a reproducible test case? Something I can take to my browser, run, and see the problem.

Comment: OK, give me a few minutes to create a fiddle. The API's not public, so I'll have to find something else.

Comment: @Escher jsfiddle offers test ajax endpoints. http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: No it doesn't take an arg. Is that the problem?

Comment: It's not. At least, not the problem you're observing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurs because your function is returning `undefined` (in other words, getting to the end of the function block before it returns) before it ever gets a chance to return `Promise.resolve('1')`.

Your function has to immediately return a Promise object, which becomes pending before eventually resolving inside your AJAX handler.

I'd also add error handling using the provided `reject` argument, as is standard for Promise objects.

```
function getFirstData(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // encapsulate code in a promise which returns immediately
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "/echo/json"
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
              first_data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              return resolve('1');
          }
          else {
            return reject('There was an error!') // reject the promise if error occurs
          } 
      }
      xhr.open("GET", url, true);
      xhr.send();
    });
}
```

And then catch it in the thenable chain:

```
getFirstData()
.then(getSecondData)
.catch(function(err){Throw err}) // catch the error if it throws
.then(createPage);
```

See working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zun466j3/1/)

Answer (score 3):

`getFirstData` isn't returning a promise it returns `undefined`, which is not thenable.

```
function getFirstData(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "/API/first-data?format=json"
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
              first_data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              resolve('1');
          }
      }
      xhr.open("GET", url, true);
      xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this function does not handle errors. Although, I'd leave it as an exercise for OP to do.